# If $a \mid c$ and $b \mid c$, is it then true that $ab \mid c$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For any natural numbers $a, b, c$, if $a \mid c$ and $b \mid c$ then $ab \mid c$.

Determine if its true or not.

My answer was false

Comment: To prove something is false, just provide a counterexample. For example, $a=2$, $b=4$, $c=12$, which an example of what your attempt is trying to show.

Comment: Take an example..$b=c=4,a=2$

Comment: $a=10, b=5, c=20$

Comment: Another one: $a=b=c=2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $d:=\gcd(a,b)$. Then in general,  we need $ad \mid c$  and $bd \mid c$ in order to have $ab \mid c$.

As noted in comments, a simple counterexample is sufficient to disprove the given claim. To illustrate the above, take $(a,b,c) = (4,6,12)$ and note that $d=2$ and $ad= 8 \nmid 12$.

I'm not sure I understand your use of fractions as a proof. Maybe you meant to have them the other way up?

Comment: Ah yeah i see thank you everyone for the feedback, ill try find another example of one which i think is true  so i can see how the contradiction proof works

Answer (score 1):

If  $a \mid c,$ $b \mid c,$ and $\gcd(a,b)=1$ then it actually
is true that $ab \mid c$.
Yet it is also still true that $\frac ac \cdot \frac bc = \frac {ab}{c^2}.$
Hence you *cannot* use the fact that 
$\frac ac \cdot \frac bc = \frac {ab}{c^2}$
in order to disprove the original conjecture.

When you are trying to disprove a conjecture that is worded "for any $x$"
or "for all $x$", it is usually advisable *not* to try to work with $x$ in general, but just find *one specific value* that you can plug in for $x$
for which the conjecture turns out to be false.

In this case the conjecture is about "any natural numbers $a, b, c,$"
in other words for any $a,$ for any $b,$ and for any $c,$ so you just need
to choose one specific value for each of those variables. Just guessing what to substitute for each variable is not a good strategy; it's better to actually think about what would make the conjecture not work and choose an example like that.
Several such choices have been suggested already.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback :) !